# One Dependent variable and five independent variable? Is GLM appropriate?

Tags: generalized-linear-model

The aim of this study was to compare body condition using a scaled mass index (SMI) between seven skink sub-populations between time, habitat type, sex and between age class. We predict that skinks living in areas of degraded forest habitat will have a lower SMI than those in less disturbed coastal habitats and that SMI may have changed over time as habitats have become more degraded and disturbed. Additionally, body condition was compared between sex and age classes at each site, which may indicate more vulnerable individuals within the population.
My question:- is it appropriate to use GLM. As my independent variable is body condition and independent variables are seven skink sub-populations, time, habitat type, sex, age class.

Answer (score 1):

From your description, I assume body condition is a continuous variable? In this case you would normally start with a linear regression, not a glm.

Comment: Can you guide me more as there are more than two independent variables? More specifically can you guide me about SPSS procedure to do so?

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=multiple+regression+spss ;)